# Can't use account after windows 10 update

Tags: windows, windows-10, windows-update, user-accounts, updates

I have a lab with 30 pc with Windows 10 installed, managed with a AD Domain. Randomly (I suppose that this happen after a system update) I am unable to logon with domain account. Only the local account works, but when the desktop is loaded I can't do anything: the windows bar doesn't respond and the only programs that runs are task manager and cmd. And the local admin account is loaded like Guest account. In this way I need to reboot the system and use Windows restore tools to open a admin cmd.

I have tried this solutions:

- restore point: the process failed for an error on disk...on every pc!!!
- DISM.exe /Online /Cleanup-image /Restorehealth: it has worked only in a machine, where I was able to log on with domain admin Account. For other machine when I try to use this tool from recovery option the system tell me that I can't use the online restore because I'm in recovery tool
- sfc /scannow: no error on disk
- from a cmd in the recovery tool area I have tried to create a new user with admin role, but when I come back to logon screen it doesn't work (the logon failed)
- from a cmd in the recovery tool area I have tried to elevate my old local admin to admin role (net localgroup administrators UserName /add), but when I log on the profile was guest too
- from a cmd in the recovery tool area I have tried to use wuauclt command to update the system but the cmd can't find the program
- from a cmd in the recovery tool area I have tried to open power shell command to update the system but the cmd can't find the program

I have ended up my ideas...someone can help me?!

Comment: You are sure it is domain joined? I’ve seen similar issues before requiring the AD object to be recreated and the computer rejoined. It may have fallen off when updated.

Comment: I can give it a try. But how can I join to domain from a prompt? The only admin interface that I have is the cmd in recovery tools. Additionally, I have problem with local account too: after the logon with my local admin account, the system tell me that it is a guest account and only the task manager works. Other elements, like windows menu bar, don't respond.

Comment: If your machine has a domain account, it should have been domain joined at some point... meaning there should be an admin of Active Directory that could recreate your computer object... if you’re not able to do that yourself, do you have access to an internal IT HelpDesk? I’m confused...

Comment: The problem is on machine, not in the domain configuration. I can recreate the computer object on the domain server, but the problem remain because it is related to the machine. And in this machine the domain account doesn't work (wrong password) while the local account is recognized like guest account (and the 90% of function doesn't work). In the only pc that I was able to fix (for some unkown reasons - look second point of my list) , everything comes back to normal without rejoin the pc to domain or without recreate the object in the AD.

Comment: Have you tried ‘gpuodate /force’ to force most current domain cress to cache on the device? Do this while connected to the corp net (physically or VPN).

Comment: I have tried, but the cmd can't find the program